# How can I count the number of words in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a query that will return the total number of words in a column?  I found some code that can allow me to count the words in a string, but cannot apply it to the entire column.

I first create the function found from http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/count-words.aspx:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordCount] ( @InputString VARCHAR(4000) ) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @WordCount      INT

SET @Index = 1
SET @WordCount = 0

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar = ' ' AND @Char != ' '
        SET @WordCount = @WordCount + 1

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @WordCount

END
GO
```

Next, test it on a string:

```
    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(4000)
    SET @String = 'Health Insurance is an insurance against expenses incurred through illness of the insured.'


SELECT [dbo].[WordCount] ( @String )
```

In this example, this returns 13.  However, I am trying to get the totals of an entire column.  For example, if I had a column with 2 rows and each row contained this string in it, I would like it to return 26 to reflect the total words in the column rather than an individual string.

Comment: what do you mean by `if I had a column with 2 of these strings in it, I would like to return 26` ?

Comment: the function counts the words in the string and returns 13.  However, I want to count all words in a column.  So if there were two rows in a column that were identical to the string " Health Insurance is an insurance against expenses incurred through illness of the insured." it should return 26 since there are two rows (I've updated the last sentence to clarify)

Comment: Is this what you want ? `SELECT SUM ([dbo].[WordCount] ( thecolumn) ) FROM yourtable`

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Squirrel's answer works, but on small datasets.  Is there is a better method that will work on larger datasets with tens of millions of records?  Also, I cannot mark this as correct as it is in the comments.  I will give your answer the credit if you post it as a reply.  In the meantime, I've marked a duplicate for reference purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sum this function call:

```
SELECT SUM([dbo].[WordCount]([my_column]))
FROM   [my_table]
```

Comment: This works but only on very small data sets.  However, is there a better (even if its dirtier and not as accurate) to get these results on a table with tens of millions of records?

Answer (score 4):

Why you are using `WHILE` loop, since you can just count the words as

```
WITH TBL AS
(
  SELECT 'One' Str
  UNION
  SELECT 'One Two'
  UNION
  SELECT 'One Two Three'
  UNION
  SELECT 'One Two Three Four'
)
SELECT SUM((LEN(Str) - LEN(REPLACE(Str, ' ', ''))) + 1)
FROM TBL;
--WHERE Str <> '' AND Str IS NOT NULL;
```

This way you will count all the words in that column.

Comment: provided that you have only single space in between the words. You will need to handle cases where there are multiple continuous spaces

Answer (score 0):

Another [word count using SQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/replace-t-sql-string-function.aspx) solution is provided at referred tutorial where instead of WHILE loop REPLACE SQL function is used for determining the count.

The problem or missing part with these SQL solutions that they do not consider patterns like web addresses. Since a URL has ".com" that will cause plus 1 in the total word count.

All scalar functions can be applied to a table's specific columns' values as

```
SELECT dbo.scalarFunction(columnName) FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

STRING_SPLIT was introduced in SQL 2016 and I use it for my counting as following (TRIM is to remove any spaces before or after the string)

```
  SELECT value AS number_of_words
  FROM YourTable a
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(TRIM(a.YourStringColumnWithWordsToCount),' ')
```

It returns you all the words and now you can either SUM on the value or SUM DISTINCT if you need to eliminate duplicate words (e.g. if you send words for translation).